# Symfony and JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I have two issues with the use of JMSSerializerBundle (but I am quite a noob in php programming and of course in symfony..).

So.. let's start from the first, more urgent, one: serializing/deserializing dates.

My service accept a date paramter in the format: 'yyyy-mm-dd' (the format is "generic".. I mean a 4digit year, 2 digit month and 2 digit day).

I have to deserialize and serialize this.
So.. because I thought annotations could be easier I added `* @SerializerAnnotation\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'")` annotation... It doesn't work, The doc says that I should use double quote to specify format, but if I do that, a parse exception occurs.

Any advice? I can also try a .yml configuration, but I don't know where to put it..

Second: when I create a `Person` object (POST action) I also have a password field. So I'd like to deserialize it. Of course I don't want to deserialize it.. Is there a way to specify an exclusion policy for serializing and another for deserializing?

Edit:
Currently I removed the bundle and manually mapped from array to my object (and viceversa).

Comment: I know it's quite a while. Did you manage to make it work? If so can you please provide your solution

Comment: I'm sorry. In the end I gave up. It was a project I was doing in my free time, and.. I had no more free time :(

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you forgot to write the "greater than" character to finish the format part:

```
* @SerializerAnnotation\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")
```

And as for the exclusion goes, check the [Exclusion Strategies](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) chapter on JMS's cookbook!

Comment: For the exclusion strategies you mean using groups? About the format: this is my current format `* @SerializerAnnotation\Type("DateTime<'Y-m-d'>")` and the result is `"birthDate":"2013-02-18T19:49:15+0100"`, so.. it does not seems the right result

Comment: Wow there's an JMS cookbook! Why isn't this linked from the other page on jsyst's site?